# DB Migration complication

Tags: sql-server, migration

I am currently working on a database migration use case where the requirement is to migrate a database of size 220 GB from a source SQL Server 2005 (installed on Windows 2003 Server R2 edition, residing in a data center) to a destination SQL Server 2019 Developer edition (installed on Windows 10 Pro, residing on an on-premise machine).

I am using the normal backup/restore option in SSMS. It works fine for smaller databases, but when I try to move the larger database file (`.bak`) from the source to the destination across the network and then restore it at the destination, the restore option fails to recognize the backup set.

It looks like a file corruption problem to me, but it would be good to know if someone has experienced this before and ways to deal with it.

Comment: What error is SQL throwing?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 Compatibility level is not supported in SQL Server 2019. I think you would first have to restore the Database to a SQL Server 2008 R2 (or so).

Just as a hint, you can split your backup into multiple files:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Manu, I feel it's not a compatibility problem as I am able to restore smaller databases successfully from 2005 into 2019. It's just the issue with the larger databases.

Comment: Hi @AjayGanapathy, have you tried splitting the backup into multiple files as seen in the screenshot above?

Comment: @AjayGanapathy Just because it appears to be working for your smaller databases, doesn't mean it actually is fully. I believe Manu is correct, and I thought in some cases you might even have to do multiple restores between multiple versions (though for 2019 it sounds like a restore and new backup from version 2008 or later is sufficient). Please see [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/487005/could-it-be-possible-to-restore-the-sql-server-200.html) which has further helpful information.